# Pen tool jumping and not drawing accurately

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, snapping

When I try to use the pen tool in Adobe Illustrator to draw around individual shapes in detail the pen jumps away from where I have selected, as if it is restricted. For example see the image below, if I click where the star is, the pen tool lands beside it rather than on it. I need this for precise outlines, is there a way to configure it or the likes?

[image]

Comment: i just had this happen, and it worked to turn off view> snap to pixel

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely caused by having snap feature enabled.

Make sure you have snap to grid turned off *View → Snap to Grid* (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>)

Comment: Disabling Snap to Point can also help if the artwork is very small... then of course, Align to Pixel Grid :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, these small things irritate a lot when you start learning. You saved me buddy

Answer (score -1):

Version: 2018 Adobe CC
Fix that worked for me:  Disable View > Smart Guides